# U+F00D character appended to filename if the script file has CRLF line endings

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When trying to run a simple script in *wsl* based *bash*:

```
echo 00000 >my_file
cat my_file
```

```
my_file
```

A weird looking character, that looks like a **large dot** under windows, is appended to the end of the output filename!!

After some research the character was identified as `U+F00D` (chr 61453), and further research showed that this happens only when the script file has `CRLF` line endings and doesn't when using `LF` ones.

My question is, what is the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Not really a programming question. When you repost it to [su] or [unix.se] (after reading their help on on-topic questions), be sure to include the output of `uname -srv` in the body of your question. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Please share `xxd -p my_file | tr -d '\n'`.

Comment: Can you confirm that it's the unallocated code point U+F00D and not the expected carriage return U+000D? How did you determine this?

Comment: `uname -srv`   `Linux 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #1432-Microsoft Mon Aug 18 18:18:00 PST 2020` and I was working on a shell script... doesn't this qualify as a programming question.. what to do now..?

Comment: `xxd -p my_file | tr -d '\n'` Gives a `No such file or directory` even when I try to drag and drop the file directly in the wsl window!

Comment: Further investigations from the shell side show that the file name was stored as `'my_file'$'\r'` completely different from the windows side of things!

Answer (score 1):

Windows side investigations showed a `U+F00D` (61453) character appended to the file name. But Further investigations from the shell side, revealed that the file was stored under the name

```
'my_file'$'\r'
```

having both an end of line character and the expected extra carriage return! (as hinted by [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy)) completely different from the windows side of things! .